# Invoking a text box and action method for several input text fields?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm new to jsf and not sure how to frame the question in a right way. I'm doing a name lookup functionality and my input form is as follows:

1. Accept input from a text field.(Backed by managed bean and
   getters and setters)
2. Invoke the action using command button.
3. Display it back on the UI.

I'm not able to paste the entire code because of confidentiality.

```
<h:form>
    <p:outputLabel value="ABC" />
    <p:inputText id="a" value="#{mybean.variable}" size="10" /> 
    <p:commandButton value="Check" actionListener="#{mybean.getName()}" update="name">
    </p:commandButton>
    <p:inputText id="name" value="#{mybean.Value}" />
</h:form>
```

The above mentioned works fine,However I have 5 input text fields and their corresponding action methods like as follows:

```
    <p:outputLabel value="DEF" />
    <p:inputText id="b" value="#{mybean.variable1}" size="10" /> 
    <p:commandButton value="Check" actionListener="#{mybean.getName()}" update="name" >
    </p:commandButton>
    <p:inputText id="name" value="#{mybean.Value}" />
</h:form>
```

and so on.

When I put all the text boxes and their corresponding actions,the input is not passed to the backend and the console does not display anything.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: please create a good [mcve]. In your second not working example there are as many inputs as in the working one. And please look at the edits I made to your post

Comment: There is not an immediate attribute somewhere and does not occure a convertation/validation error?